# Integration of differential form on ellipsoidal surface with singularity in origin

Tags: integration, differential-geometry, manifolds, riemannian-geometry

As picture below ,I want to compute the (2) , because there is a singularity in $\{0\}$  and $\omega$ is closed . So ,I have 
$$
\int_M\omega=\int _{\partial B_1(0)} \omega 
$$
I think there is a singularity in the $\{0\}$ , so , I think I can't use Stock theory by 
$$
\int _{\partial B_1(0)} \omega  =\int_{B_1(0)} d\omega
$$
So, I can't compute it. How should to do it ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On $\partial B_1(0)$, $\|x\|=1$, thus

$$\int_{\partial B_1(0)} \omega = \int_{\partial B_1(0)}\omega_0, $$

where

$$\omega_0  = \sum_{i=1}^n (-1)^{i+1} x_i dx^1 \wedge \cdots \wedge \widehat{dx^i} \wedge \cdots \wedge dx^n.$$

Now the singularity is gone and you can apply Stokes' theorem.

Comment: So，  it is the volume of the $B_1(0)$ ?

Comment: Up to a constant. @lanse7pty

Comment: Whether up to a constant  n ? Is it  right that $\int_{\partial B_1(0)}\omega_0=\int_{B_1(0) }  n dx^1 \wedge \cdots \wedge dx^i \wedge \cdots \wedge dx^n.$

Comment: @lanse7pty yes. ${}{}{}$